# Python - SqlAlchemy - how to insert gracefully, by avoiding duplicates?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

I've tried this, but without luck:

```
def sqlTryInsert(result_obj):
 try:
  session.add(result_obj)
  session.flush()
  session.commit() 
 except (exc.SQLAlchemyError, exc.DBAPIError) as e:
  code, msg = e.orig
  if code == 1062:
    # send warning
    pass
```

I still get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, 
"Duplicate entry '...' for key 'hash'") 
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO results (...) VALUES (...)'] [parameters: (...)] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Comment: why not just catching the `IntegrityError` and continue execution? do you have more logic in except?

Comment: I don't know how many IntegrityErrors are there and I might allow some unwanted ones to pass.